# in ios 7 SKScene after dismissing view controller no response

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, skscene

In the start of a game after initializing first `SKScene` in root view controller I have menu where 3 button(sknodes) lead to other skscenes and one more button which leads to second view controller. After presenting the second view controller when I want to go back to first scene I use dismiss view controller, the root view controller with first scene appears and first scene is frozen.

If you click on the button that leads to some of the first 3 scenes then a new scene presents itself, but under the first scene. I cannot see it, but I can hear the sound of other scenes.

This is happening on devices on ios7; on ios8 it works like charm, the scene is not freezing. I present view controller like this

```
[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:secondviewcontroller animated:NO completion:nil];
```

and dismiss

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

I tried with delegates, segue its same result, every possible solution here.

Comment: How are you playing the sounds?

Comment: They are played from audio player initialized from singletone manager. After I dismiss view controller first scene is freezed if I click on buttons next scene is present under first scene, i can see nsloged values writen in console from next scenes initializations.